# pandas - group based on values from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'fuz', 'baz', 'fuz', 'coo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                          'three', 'three', 'four', 'one']})
```

It looks like that:

```
    A      B
0  foo    one
1  bar    one
2  foo    two
3  bar    two
4  fuz  three
5  baz  three
6  fuz   four
7  coo    one
```

I would like to create a new column `group`. A group aggregates combinations of unique values in columns A + B.

It looks at unique values for each column. Then is looks at values in the other column for elements already in the group.

The result would look like this:

```
    A      B    group
0  foo    one     1
1  bar    one     1
2  foo    two     1
3  bar    two     1
4  fuz  three     2
5  baz  three     2
6  fuz   four     2
7  coo    one     1
```

In this example, we start at `foo` in column A. All `foo` will be in `group1`. The associated values in B are `one` and `two` => also in `group1`.

The associated values of `one` and `two` in column A are `foo`, `bar` and `coo` => also in `group1`.

The same principle gives us `group2`.

What would be the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you were looking for, it is a bit hard-coded but has the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'fuz', 'baz', 'fuz', 'coo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                          'three', 'three', 'four', 'one']})
g1 = df[df['A']=='foo']
df['group'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(g1['A'])|df['B'].isin(g1['B']),1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to the answer posted by zipa,I think my code can do on all situations，for example,the data of df will be divided into 3 groups

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bae', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'fuz', 'baz', 'fzz', 'coo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                          'three', 'three', 'four', 'one']})
df['group'] = [None]*len(df)
i = 1
while True:
  value = df[df['group'].isnull()].iloc[0, 0]
  g1 = df[df['A']==value]
  df['group']=np.where(df['A'].isin(g1['A'])|df['B'].isin(g1['B']),i,df['group'])
  if not any(df['group'].isnull()):
     break
  i += 1
print(df)
```

the resule like this

```
         A      B group
0  foo    one     1
1  bae    one     1
2  foo    two     1
3  bar    two     1
4  fuz  three     2
5  baz  three     2
6  fzz   four     3
7  coo    one     1
```

Hope to help you